# XML DOM ERROR when executing Python program in perl

Tags: python, xml, matlab, xml-parsing

I have a program written in Perl, and I want to execute this program in MATLAB. In this program I am calling an XML file, but on execution, I am getting XML: DOM error as `Error using perl (line 80) System error: Can't locate XML/DOM.pm in @INC, etc.` How can I get out of this error?

Program is executing in Perl very well...

Comment: Added code for error, fixed spelling, and removed extra text

Answer (score 0):

Matlab brings it's own perl installation located at `fullfile(matlabroot, 'sys\perl\win32\bin\')`. Probably here the additional resources are missing. Navigate to this folder and install the requirements using `ppm`

Comment: YES I GOT,  But how i can instal  XML:DOM in MATLAB Kindly help me...  perl program is calling XML file, so error is coming.

Comment: You can change the version of PERL that MATLAB uses by pointing it to a different location, where the new executable exists.

You can edit PERL.M and have MATLAB use a newer version of the PERL executable that you wish.

If your open perl.m by typing "edit perl.m", around line 65 your will see the following:

      perlCmd = fullfile(matlabroot, 'sys\perl\win32\bin\');
Comment this code and add your new path as the perlCmd variable.